# Codeigniter: A nice straight forward tutorial on how to build a reset password/forgotten password?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've built a full sign up system with user account activation, login, validation, captcha etc. To complete this I now need to implement a forgot password/reset password feature..

I have created one function that generates a random password 8 characters, another method that takes that random password word and applies sha1 and hashing.

Also one that takes that hashed password and stores it in a table in the database.

I will keep these methods to one side as they might come in handy later on but for now I would like to know if anyone can point me to a nice tutorial for creating a password reset feature for my website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461119/codeigniter-lost-password-feature-how-to-implement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a password reset page with a form and an input for their email address
2. When they submit the form

   - send an email to that email address with the new random password and a link to a reset page
   - also store the new password in a new row in mysql named `pass_reset`
3. After they click the link in the email.. let them type in the new password
4. Check against the db, if (correct){ let them enter a new password }else{ fail }